# npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree

Tags: ionic-cli

I'm Try to create new ionic project,
But facing this error
Is there anyone know why I got this Error messages ?
and how to fix it ?

I tried:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

and

`--force`, or `--legacy-peer-deps`
these flag with my command
but no any luck.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a dependency for ionic-app-base in your package.json file? I could't find a package with this name in npm registry. Try removing this line from package.json and delete node-modules and run npm install again.

Comment: https://imgur.com/xXxwn57

Comment: Strangely, your ionic start command has created your project with version 0.0.0 which is wrong as usually it starts with 0.0.1.  I guess there is something wrong with the ionic cli. Try reinstalling it. https://imgur.com/a/P1dpp68

Comment: yes i think the issue come from after updating npm 6 to 7

Answer (score 1):

I've [sent a PR](https://github.com/ionic-team/starters/pull/1671) to the starters template updating angular and should prevent the errors.

But you can also downgrade npm from 7 to 6 as workaround.

Comment: Seems that I am having the same problem as of today.